# Communicating device to device

Tags: android, communication, google-cloud-messaging

I have been looking for the best way to send texts and images device to device, not via "bluetooth" or "wifi direct" e.g. SnapChat.

Does this type of application need the developer to have their own servers or can it be done using purely the Android infrastructure? I have read allot about the Google cloud messenger service, can this be used for device to device? If anyone could prod me in the right direction of any tutorials/articals it would be much appreciated.

Or any suggestions for companies where you can buy server space?

many thanks

Comment: Have you ever read this:https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en? and you can also find tutorial in this page too:http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Answer (score -1):

Android C2DM is just a messaging service , using this you can just send notification(A Small Message) to your device. Which actually gets triggered from Application Server only.

I am sure about that you will definitely need your server to achieve this. In Market we have famous app WhatsApp , WeChat etc. They use their own server.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to use the server SDK on Android. The only problem is figuring out the address of devices you want to message. I've built a little IM application that would send messages directly between devices after exchanging the addresses.

Comment: No, using GCM (formerly C2DM).